# How to change Custom Control default size

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, controls, custom-controls

I'm new to adding Custom Controls in VB.NET.
I want a PictureBox-like control that has a default size and picture, both preferably unchangeable.
I started by adding a new Class to my project and then added the following code:

```
Public Class CustomControl
Inherits Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateControl()  
        MyBase.OnCreateControl()
        Me.Image = Global.Mazerino.My.Resources.Resources.ControlImage           
        MyBase.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(20, 20) 'Also tried setting Width and Height 
                                                      'properties instead. 
    End Sub
End Class
```

I executed the project, closed, then added the control; the image was added, but the size wasn't changed. The default control's size was 150, 50.

So I instead added the following code:

```
Private ControlSize As Size = New Size(10, 10)
Overloads Property Size As Size        
    Get
        Return ControlSize
    End Get  

    Set(value As Size)
    'Nothing here...
    End Set
End Property
```

But it didn't work either, so then I tried:

```
Shadows ReadOnly Property Size As Size
    Get
        Return ControlSize
    End Get
End Property
```

Which worked when adding the control to the form, but when I executed the program, I got the following error: "Property Size is only ReadOnly". When double clicking it, it leads to the following code in the Form Design:

```
Me.CustomControl1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(10, 10)
```

Which leads me to change the property to read and write, but when I do this, once again, the Control size stays at 150,50.

So, how can I set a default size to a specific one and not have trouble adding the control to my Form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the min and max size?

```
Public Class CustomControl Inherits Windows.Forms.PictureBox
     Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateControl()  
         MyBase.OnCreateControl()
         MyBase.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
         Me.Image = Global.Mazerino.My.Resources.Resources.ControlImage           
         MyBase.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(20, 20) 'Also tried setting Width and Height 
                                                       'properties instead.
         MyBase.MaximumSize = New Size(20,20)
         MyBase.MinimumSize = New Size(20,20) 
     End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Public Class CustomControl : Inherits Windows.Forms.PictureBox

    Private ReadOnly INMUTABLE_SIZE As Size = New Size(20, 20)

    Public Shadows Property Size As Size
        Get
            Return INMUTABLE_SIZE
        End Get
        Set(value As Size)
            MyBase.Size = INMUTABLE_SIZE
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnSizeChanged(e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.Size = INMUTABLE_SIZE
        MyBase.OnSizeChanged(e)
    End Sub

End Class
```